# How to automatically edit an existing .dat file via site/small downloaded file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, minecraft

I have recently been working on a project for the Minecraft Community, and which is a simple little program that would run when clicked from a website. This program would edit the servers.dat file within the .minecraft folder, and add a new entry to the NBT file, which would list 1: if it is a hidden address, 2: the actual IP, and 3: the Title that would show up ingame. I am either looking for a way that could be implemented in either in Bootstrap (by Twitter) or by downloading a small file and running automatically, then delete it self.
Overall, I just need help figuring out how to create an editor that can place pre-defined data to an existing file. Thanks! :)

Comment: Bootstrap is a client-side framework. You cannot modify files on the client's computer with it. You need to write a script that your user downloads and executes. What platforms do you expect the user to have?

Comment: Preferably Java, since Minecraft requires Java to run, neither would work without it.

Comment: In that case then I suggest you start learning Java. [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaIntroduction/article.html) seems like a good place to start. When you have more concrete questions (such as: How do I read a file in Java? How do I write a file in Java?) you can come back here and ask them, though in a lot of cases they would already have been answered so make sure you search first.

Comment: Also, NBT is a very specialized format. I would look for some libraries to interact with it rather than trying to do it yourself.